# How do I loop a specific function from a package in r?

Tags: r, function, loops, package, geosphere

I have  list of dates like this.

> OnlyDates
> [1] "2018-01-22" "2018-01-22" "2018-01-22" "2018-01-22" "2018-01-22" "2018-01-22" "2018-01-22" "2018-01-22" "2018-01-22" "2018-01-22" "2018-01-22"
> [353] "2018-09-25" "2018-09-25" "2018-09-25" "2018-09-25" "2018-09-25" "2018-09-25" "2018-09-25" "2018-09-25" "2018-10-10" "2018-10-10" "2018-10-10"
> [364] "2018-10-10" "2018-10-10" "2018-10-10" "2018-10-10" "2018-10-10" "2018-10-10" "2018-10-10" "2018-10-10" "2018-10-10" "2018-10-10" "2018-10-10"

I want to loop a function that calculates hours of photoperiod in a specific day, and prints it in another column called "Photoperiod". The function is called 'daylength', from the package 'geosphere'

The am trying something like this:

```
for (i in OnlyDates {print(daylength(-43.39, "i"))})
```

-43.39 is the latitude, and "i" should be the date written as: "2021-08-05"

Example of the function alone:

```
daylength(-43.39, "2021-08-05")
```

Which returns
`[1] 9.897292`

Instead, with my code I get:

> Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :
> error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'print': character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Anyone can give some light on this?
Thanks,
Leo

Comment: can't you simply do `daylength(-43.39, c("2021-08-05", "2018-01-22", "2018-10-10"))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `i` (not `"i"`) without quotation mark.

besides bracket in `for` loop is in wrong place. you should end iteration condition first, then define body

```
for (i in OnlyDates) {print(daylength(-43.39, i))}
```

Comment: Thank you! 
I am a newbie with loops. This worked

Comment: But I still don't manage to print the results into a new vector

Comment: what do you mean 'print into vector'? to assign result to vector try `vector <- daylength(-43.39, OnlyDates)`